# What string key and value map attribute can be placed with createAccount function with Smack api?

Tags: smack

I really have not tried this, I am just curious what are the attributes that can be set with createAccount with AccountManager:

```
createAccount(String username, String password, Map<String,String> attributes)
```

Can I put any String key and value, or there is a defined standard for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes are obtained by calling

```
accountManager.getAccountAttributes()
```

Check the javadoc for the createAccount() method that you mentioned.  At the bottom.

```
See Also:
    getAccountAttributes()
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation I can see a bunch of attributes, however from within the Openfire server I can only see first name, last name and email attribute. Would that mean that the getAttributes would just output 3 items? Also does this mean that I can only add attributes defined in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

```
name -- the user's name.
first -- the user's first name.
last -- the user's last name.
email -- the user's email address.
city -- the user's city.
state -- the user's state.
zip -- the user's ZIP code.
phone -- the user's phone number.
url -- the user's website.
date -- the date the registration took place.
misc -- other miscellaneous information to associate with the account.
text -- textual information to associate with the account.
remove -- empty flag to remove account.
```

See [AccountManager javadoc](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.html)